# How to update a TinyMCE instance when options are changed?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I would like to refresh my TinyMCE instance when the   options: { language: "fr" } is updated. Is there a way to apply the new option or to reload the instance?

I want to change language dynamically with Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, your_editor_id);
```

alter your configuration paramters and call

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, your_editor_id);
```

If you do not know how to edit your tinymce paramters you may use this call

```
var init_obj = {
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    ....
};

new tinymce.Editor(id_of_your_textarea_to_become_an_editor, init_obj, tinymce.EditorManager).render();
```